# How to run cmd command every time one is executed?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to do something like this:

when a command is executed in the prompt it will execute this

```
pause  
cls
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Enter this: `yourCommand & pause & cls`

Comment: check also doskey command.